# Is there any easy way / API to find out the number of pipelines on a gocd server?

Tags: go-cd

Sorry for the brief question, but just wondering if there's an API to find out the number of pipelines on a GoCD server.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pipeline Groups API](https://api.gocd.io/current/#pipeline-groups) will give you what you need after some JSON parsing.

```
$ curl 'https://ci.example.com/go/api/config/pipeline_groups' \
  -u 'username:password'
```

Returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

[
  {
    "pipelines": [
      {
        "stages": [
          {
            "name": "up42_stage"
          }
        ],
        "name": "up42",
        "materials": [
          {
            "description": "URL: https://github.com/gocd/gocd, Branch: master",
            "fingerprint": "2d05446cd52a998fe3afd840fc2c46b7c7e421051f0209c7f619c95bedc28b88",
            "type": "Git"
          }
        ],
        "label": "${COUNT}"
      }
    ],
    "name": "first"
  }
]
```

Comment: BTW I have a golang tool to get stats based on a config file https://github.com/jamesbloomer/go-go-stats

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the config.xml file and parse it. [from the config repo](https://docs.gocd.io/current/advanced_usage/config_repo.html) or via http.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can just get the cctray file from your server at http://yourgoserver/go/cctray.xml and parse it.

It contains information about all the pipelines (including its stages)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [yagocd](https://github.com/grundic/yagocd):

```
from yagocd import Yagocd

go = Yagocd(server='https://build.gocd.io')

# login as guest
go._session.get('https://build.gocd.io/go/plugin/interact/gocd.guest.user.auth.plugin/index')

print(len(list(go.pipelines)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. You can get the desired output in different ways. The first easy way to get the number of pipelines and other statistical information from the GoCD support URL (https://example.com/go/api/support) which requires admin privilege.

If the user does not have the admin privilege, we need to go with the GoCD `pipeline_groups` API. The below command should give you the exact result with `jq`([JSON processor](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/))

```
$ curl 'https://example.com/go/api/config/pipeline_groups' -u 'username:password' | jq -r '.[] | .pipelines[].name' | wc -l
```

**NOTE:** Still **Go Administrator** users can get the actual number of pipelines.